# List of I18n locales are not loading on dev server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am seeing a strange issue about I18n. When i call my endpoint locally i am able to see all the available list of locales and the endpoint loads successfully.

```
(byebug) I18n.available_locales
[:en, :bg, :"ca-CAT", :ca, :"da-DK", :"de-AT", :"de-CH", :de, :"en-au-ocker", :"en-AU", :"en-BORK", :"en-CA", :"en-GB", :"en-IND", :"en-MS", :nep, :"en-NG", :"en-NZ", :"en-PAK", :"en-SG", :"en-UG", :"en-US", :"en-ZA", :"es-MX", :es, :fa, :"fi-FI", :fr, :he, :id, :it, :ja, :ko, :"nb-NO", :nl, :pl, :"pt-BR", :pt, :ru, :sk, :sv, :tr, :uk, :vi, :"zh-CN", :"zh-TW"]
```

We deployed our project to dev but we seeing the error `en-US is not a valid locale` so looks like its not loading all the locales on dev server.

It happens for other locales too e.g for de `de is not a valid locale`.
I searched online but i cant find the solution why this is happening.

Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: Check `available_locales` config in prod env, and don't forget to restart the server if you'll change config

Comment: @Vasilisa I dont have `available_locales` config in prod env.

Comment: did you check in the en-US locale **file** that the entry for locale is **en-US** right?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `application.rb`

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
```

Have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/408), it may help with this issue.